# Post processing for generated methods of Core Data

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I have the following: a Core Data entity named `Event`. An event can have a start and end date both of which the user can enter. However, an event can also have child events in which case the start and end dates of the parent need to be calculated from the child event. There's no programmatically imposed limit to the level of nesting of events. To support this, Core Data has generated the following methods:

```
- (void)addSubEventsObject:(Event *)value;

- (void)removeSubEventsObject:(Event *)value;
```

At various points in my application I need to display information about events which means I will need to calculate start- and end dates for events that have child events.

Basically I see two scenarios: (1) calculate when needed, start- and end date of parent events are virtual (2) calculate as a child event is added and change parent start and/or end date based on the added child event.

I'm tempted to to write for scenario (2) however that would mean I would need to do some post processing after the default generated Core Data methods are executed. Is that possible? If so, how?

EDIT: I'm looking for a way to attach some processing to the generated methods that is performed after the generated methods have run. The crux is that this should survive a regeneration of the Event class by Core Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple options:

1. Have your client take a look at [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator) which aims to solve this problem by generating two classes for each entity, one which holds your custom code, and the other which is continuously overwritten as the model changes.
2. Use a category.

Comment: I decided to go with the category. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you right, you just want to change the date property of your event after its child event is created.That's possible

In your

```
 -(void)addSubEventObject(Event*):value
```

Or in some other methods,where you've got your new child event,you can easily set new parent's date by something like this:

```
//generating a new child event here and calculating a date for it's parent
[[newChildEvent parentEvent]setStartDate:someGeneratedStartDate];
[context save:error];
```

**EDIT**

You can try to listen to `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`

If you want to read about it, here is a good article by MZarra

http://www.cimgf.com/2011/10/14/parent-watching-its-child/

Comment: True, but these methods are generated so if I add code to them (to set the start date of the parent or call a method that does that) that code will disappear the next time I regenerate the Event class...

Comment: You regenerate your entity class so often? Then, you can just save it somewhere before you regenerateit, or copy to clipboard- why not to do it this way?

Comment: The other way to go is to add an observer for that method call anf berform some proccessing after that notification is called.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's not an option to fiddle about with scraps of code after the generation of entity classes. A requirement from my client. I'll look into setting an observer.